# Загрузка данных из файла в StringGrid

Tags: c++builder, c++

```
void __fastcall TForm1::bSaveClick(TObject *Sender)//обработчик для клавиши "Сохранить"
{                                                                              //данные из таблицы разделяются символом ";",
if(SaveDialog1->Execute()){TStringList *pStrings = new TStringList;
                for(int i=1; i < StringGrid1->RowCount; i++)
                {
                pStrings->Add(StringGrid1->Cells[0][i] + ";" + StringGrid1->Cells[1][i] + ";" + StringGrid1->Cells[2][i]+ ";" + StringGrid1->Cells[3][i]+ ";" + StringGrid1->Cells[4][i]+ ";" + StringGrid1->Cells[5][i]+ ";" + StringGrid1->Cells[6][i]+ ";" + StringGrid1->Cells[7][i]+ ";" + StringGrid1->Cells[8][i]+ ";" + StringGrid1->Cells[9][i]+ ";" + StringGrid1->Cells[10][i]+ ";" + StringGrid1->Cells[11][i]);
               }
        pStrings->SaveToFile(SaveDialog1->FileName);
        delete pStrings;
        }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::bOpenClick(TObject *Sender)
{
if(OpenDialog1->Execute())
    {
        TStringList *pStrings = new TStringList;
        pStrings->LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1->FileName);
        StringGrid1->RowCount = pStrings->Count+1;
        StringGrid1->ColCount=10;
        for(int i=0; i < pStrings->Count; i++)
        {
            StringGrid1->Rows[i+1]->Delimiter = ';';
            StringGrid1->Rows[i+1]->DelimitedText = pStrings->Strings[i];
        }
        delete pStrings;
    }
    for(int i=StringGrid1->ColCount; i>0;i--) {
    if(StringGrid1->Cells[i][3]==" ")
    StringGrid1->ColCount--;
    }
    j=StringGrid1->ColCount;
}
```

Вот собственно вопрос: загружаются из файла строки правильно, если в них нет пробелов. Если есть пробелы, принимает как за ещё одну строку и создаёт доп. колонку в StringGrid-е.
Как сделать так, чтоб он воспринимал пробелы как часть строки, а не делитель между строками?

Answer (score 1):

Объяви **AnsiString** и структуру содержащую столько полей, сколько в **StrinGrid** столбцов, далее в каждое поле структуры пишем ячейку **StringGrid'a** и функцией **sprintf** пишем структуру в строку, а строку в файл вот смотри:

---

Прошу не ругаться если способ не подходит, в конце концов вы не уточняли как именно вам надо писать в файл)

---

```
AnsiString S;
struct SaveStorage(AnsiString One, AnsiString Two, ... ,AnsiString Ten,); //описание структуры для хранения данных таблицы

SaveStorage Storage; //Объявили структуру

FILE *in; //объявляем файл в который сэйвим

in = fopen("TestFile.txt", "wt"); //создаем файл, присваиваем имя
fclose(in);

for(i=0;i<StrinGrid->ColCount; i++) { // в цикле выдергиваем из строки таблицы дынные 
Storage.One=StringGrid->Cells[0][i];
Storage.Two=StringGrid->Cells[1][i];
...
Storage.Ten=StringGrid->Cells[9][i];

sprintf (S, "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s \n",  // заносим данные из 10 ячеек строки **StrinGrid'a** в 1 строку (/n - означает перенос в низ на новую строчку в той же строке)
Storage.One,
Storage.Two,
...
Storage.Ten)

in=fopen("TestFile.txt", "at"); //открываем созданный файл
fputs (S, in);   // пишем в него строку
fclose(in);
}
```

---

Далее загрузка из TestFile.txt в **StringGrid**

```
AnsiString One,Two, ... , Ten; //В эти строки будем писать данные из файла (структура для этого не пригодна)

in=fopen("TestFile.txt", "rt");
while(fscanf(in,"%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s\n",
&One, 
&Two,
...
&Ten)!=EOF) //проще говоря сканим данные пока не наступит конец строки в файле

{

StringGrid1->Cells[0][i]=One;  // пишем в строку **StringGrid'a** отсканенные данные из строки файла 
StringGrid1->Cells[1][i]=Two;
...
StringGrid1->Cells[9][i]=Ten;
i++;
}
fclose(in);
```

---

Способ проверял лично, все работает корректно, если конечно с кодировкой все в поряде, иначе может выдавать вместо обычного слова фигню типа - **#$<}^$**.

---

P.S так же пробовал когда то и вами описанный способ - та еще головная боль, по мне так он мягко говоря - не удобен.

Comment: Мне сказали переделать этот код который вы написали)) не могу я вернутся на шаг назад) Да он работает, но пользователь моего проекта не будет знать откуда берутся данные, а ему как раз таки это надо знать, таково условие задачи) Но всё же спасибо вам!

Comment: Аааа, ясно, ох уж эти пользователи)

Comment: Ахах дада))

Answer (score 0):

Не понял кода: не нашел в нем выгрузки строк из pStrings в ячейки Грида.
Что присходит когда:

```
..............
StringGrid1->Rows[i+1]->DelimitedText = pStrings->Strings[i]; ? 
.............
```

Comment: Rows - строка стрингрида, ей присваиваются значения pString. При попадании на делимитер, мы переходим на следующую ячайку. Эта запись равносильна StringGrid[константа][счётчик++ при каждом символе делимитра], но кроме того делимитра что я ввожу, он воспринимает ещё и стандартный - пробел. И как избежать этой ситуации чтоб он правильно заполнял мне грид, до сих пор немогу разобраться...

Answer (score 0):

```
//подсчёт столбцов
int  countCols(const char* s, char c){
    int n = 1;
    while(*s){
            if(*s == c)
                    ++n;
            ++s;
    }
    return n;
}


// заполнение таблицы из файла
void FileToGrid(const char* fn, TStringGrid* grid){
    const char* s, *p;
    const char  del = ';';

    TStringList* flst = new TStringList();
    flst->LoadFromFile(fn);

    if(! flst->Count){
        delete flst;
        return;
    }

    grid->ColCount = countCols(flst->Strings[0].c_str(), del);
    grid->RowCount = flst->Count;

    int col;
    for(int i = 0; i < flst->Count; ++i){
            s   = p = flst->Strings[i].c_str();
            col = 0;

            do {
                    if(*s == del || ! *s){
                            grid->Cells[col][i] = AnsiString(p, (s - p));
                            p = s + 1;
                            ++col;
                    }
            } while(*s++ != '\0');
     }
     delete flst;
}

...

if(OpenDialog1->Execute())
    ::FileToGrid(OpenDialog1->FileName, StringGrid1);
```